# android studio onMapReady not called

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to integrate a map view in one of my views.

I have generated a new map fragment. It comes up in a different view and works like a charm.

I then tried to integrate the code in a normal activity (one with actionbar and so forth). It kinda works - comes up on the screen fine, but onMapReady never gets called in that environment (in other words, I stay stuck in Africa, instead of going to Sydney).

Been on it for hours...

Here is the xml code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jp.artfoundui.MapsActivity" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/monument_capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

And here is the java code :

```
public class MonumentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monument);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);

    }
        /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I know this sounds dumb, but have you actually used the debugger to see if it steps into onMapReady() ? I'm looking at some of my personal code and our work basically matches up. Maybe there's something inside onMapReady that's not working?

Comment: Nice suggestion. I checked, yup, no call to onMapReady.

Comment: but as I was playing around with the debugger, I noticed that onCreate doesn't get called either. So naturally, the onMapReady never gets registered.

So now, why doesn't onCreate get called. I checked in the other demo code (the standard example that just plucks a fragment on the screen), and onCreate does indeed get called. But once I place the fragment in my activity (code above), onCreate just doesn't get called...

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer - sort of.

The whole code concerning the fragment activity never gets called. I tried several solutions to activate this fragment, but all came to a dead end...

An alternate solution is to continue using the main activity (a subclass of AppCompatActivity). It turns out that AppCompatActivity can directly implement a OnMapReadyCallback.

So I added "implement OnMapReadyCallback", and then added directly a "onMapReady" callback. Code looks like this :

```
public class MonumentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_monument);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.monument_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
[...]
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng louvres = new LatLng(48.860294, 2.338629);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(louvres).title("Marker sur le Louvres"));
    // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(louvres));
    // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(louvres, 15));
}
```

Works fine. I get a full activity (with the toolbar, menus active, and an additional floating button), and the underlying map works fine...

Comment: Still not calling