# onMapReady not always called

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have three activities:

MainActivity:

```
public void start_main_map(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.MainMap.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

MainMap:

```
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
     mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onMapReady");
    // do some serious work here
}
```

Guide:

```
private void implement_back_button() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.MainMap.class);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Whenever I go from `MainActivity` to `MainMap` I get:

```
I/MainMap: onCreate
I/MainMap: onStart
I/MainMap: onResume
I/MainMap: onMapReady
```

Yet, whenever I go from `Guide` to `MainMap` (either using the `back_button` or pressing the back key in my cellphone) I only get:

```
I/MainMap: onCreate
I/MainMap: onStart
I/MainMap: onResume
```

No, `onMapReady` - so the "serious work" is never addressed. I cannot understand this behaviour. How can ensure that `onMapReady` is called in all cases?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41365553/4432830 hope this helps

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean if you go to Map activity from Main Activity, onMapReady call but If you back from other activity to map activity, onMapReady doesnt call?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I mean

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: @Praveen, does not help at all - I already have `implements OnMapReadyCallback` in my class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finishing the Map Activity is a bit heavy handed.
You should be able to re-use the GoogleMap reference if the Google Map Activity was resumed.

Something like this should work:

```
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
protected GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();

    //Added:
    if (mMap == null) {
      mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    } else {
      doSomeSeriousWork();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Log.i(TAG, "onMapReady");
    doSomeSeriousWork();
}

public void doSomeSeriousWork() {
    // do some serious work here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pressed back from other Activity, Map Activity class just resume. And as map is already loaded before so onMapReady will not get called again.

To fix that, just finish the Map Activity before start other activity from Map Activity

Like this

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(MapActivity.class, OtherActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);

MapActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

**From `MainActivity` to `MainMap`:**

`onMapReady()` called, because `MainMap` created for the first time.

**From `Guide` to `MainMap`:**

`onMapReady()` was not called, because you are just returning back to `MainMap` and `MainMap` alreday exist in Activity `stack` and its `Map` is `ready`.

**Solution:**

Finish `MainMap` before starting `Guide` Activity.